# Is spring rsocket thread effective?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, rsocket

We know that the advantage of reactive programming (and thus spring-webflux) is the fact that only one thread is used to handle multiple client requests.

I want to make use of reactive programming with websockets instead of sse events, so I found that spring-boot-rsocket may be what I'm looking for.

It works but now I'm wondering what is happening under the hood: if more clients connect to my websocket server is only one thread handling the subscriptions? Or am I falling back to multiple threads?

My use case is a news feed, where clients keep a connection open and patiently wait for news they subscribed to. So, having one thread per client is a waste of resources and risks to put my application down.

In fact, suppose that on my production system I know I can afford a maximum number of x threads, let us say 200 for explaination sake. If each subscription request is in a thread and I have 200 clients connected at the same moment that means that the thread saturation will be reached!

Comment: why would one thread handle it? whats the source for your claim?

Comment: Edited my answer with the explaination

Comment: still, you have not posted any claim or evidence that it may be so. The entire purpose of webflux is that it is thread agnostic, any request can handle any thing at any time. Why would it be only one thread handling subscriptions? If you are worried, write a POC and try it.

Comment: I'm using the springboot-starter-rsocket so I don't know what it is under the hood, it combines servlet with websockets...maybe I could use some monitoring tool?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket it is fairly reactive, so i don't think you will have any problems using it. And you should always monitor your applications if the are running in any production environment.